# Propel: test existing object for matching the criteria

Tags: php, orm, criteria, propel

What would be the best way to ask Propel to check whether existing object (retrieved or newly created) matches some criteria.
I wonder if Propel has native ability to do this :-) I'm asking about simple ways, because doing this the complicated way is easy.
Ideally something like:

```
    $fruit = FruitPeer::doSelectOne( new Criteria ); // get whatever fruit

    $crit1 = new Criteria;
    $crit1->add(FruitPeer::REF_COLOR, 'green');      // criteria for green fruits

    if ($fruit->matches($crit1)) {                   // check if my fruit is green
        echo 'My fruit is green';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in a trivial way, since Criteria objects are only used to generate SQL queries and not to match objects. However you can just query the database again. Propel's instance pools should avoid retrieving all data again when it detects that an instance of a queried object already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing you can do is to add a condition on your primary key and then issue a count.

If you have a query (`ModelCriteria` instance instead of a plain `Criteria` instance) you can do this in one line:

```
if($critQuery1->filterByPrimaryKey($fruit->getPrimaryKey())->count() > 0) {…}
```